# SSRS issue in Sharepoint 2010. Blank columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

The images below show "Linked Room" not returning any value.

The issue is when 1st row returns a linked room with a blank value all others come as blank.

The moment i delete 1st entry all the rows are displayed properly as shown in 2nd image.

Can anyone help me find why is this issue coming?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll need to share your research with us, and tell us what you've tried to fix it. At the very least, we need more info on the expression you're using. Otherwise, it's just guessing for us.

Comment: @Jeroen i am not using any expression, i removed the expression and custom code i was using for `Linked Room` field . Its a simple caml query that returns set of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to specifically provide column names in the CAML query as shown below:

```
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">GetListItemsResponse/GetListItemsResult/listitems/data/row{@Column1,@Column2,@Column3,@Column4,@column5,@column6,@column7}</ElementPath>
```